# Do variables declared outside React functional component get destroyed/deleted/garbage collected when component unmounts? Do they create memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, garbage-collection

I want to put some variables outside the functional component because I don't want them to get re-initialized on re-render. I am wondering how they will get cleared from the memory.

Comment: They won't be cleared, and they would be available to all instances of the component. If you want to clear them, you can use the `useEffect` cleanup function. Cleaning the variables would also clean them for all other instances. 

This works fine for constant values (base api url for example), but it's a mass when you need to store dynamic values. Use `useRef` instead.